# Given the Sequence:

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> $$a_n=\frac{\cos^2(n)}{2^n}$$

I went on Symbolab to check what the answer was because I originally thought it was divergent because the $\cos^2(n)$ is bounded as follows $0 \le \cos^2(x) \le 1$. Symbolab hinted to use squeeze theorem, and I was wondering if my procedure was correct?

> $$\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} (\frac{\cos^2(n)}{2^n})$$
>   Applying Squeeze theorem I did the following:
>   $$0 \le \cos^2(n) \le 1$$
>   $$\frac{0}{2^n}\le \frac{\cos^2(n)}{2^n} \le \frac{1}{2^n}$$
>   Then I took the limit as $n \to \infty$.
>   $$\lim_\limits{n \to \infty}\frac{0}{2^n} \le \lim_\limits{n \to \infty}\frac{\cos^2(n)}{2^n} \le \lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2^n}$$
>   $\therefore$ one can say:
>   $$0 \le \lim_\limits{n \to \infty}\frac{\cos^2(n)}{2^n} \le 0 $$

Comment: This looks right, though I am not sure what you are asking?

Comment: @Norse I am asking if its right...I asked if my procedure was right?

Comment: Oh yeah, I see now... Well, your procedure is correct

Comment: Are you sure question was about a sequence, not a series? (both converge....)

Comment: Yes this argument should work.

Comment: I am currently taking Calculus 2 and they don't go over Squeeze theorem as much so its a less used route so I am constantly questioning how should I bound my function.

Comment: @coffeemath its a sequence in the book.

Comment: Notice that $cos^{2}(n)$ is bounded and $2^{-n}$ tends to zero as $n$ approaches infinity. Consequently, you may apply the squeeze theorem to conclude the given limit equals $0$.